# Add and remove input texts on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that allows a user to create custom questions.

The user needs to insert the title for the question and then choose the type of the question.

If the type of question is radio button, checkbox or a select menu it should appear a div "availableOptions" that shows by default two input texts so the user can insert some option values.

**Doubt:**

When this "availableOptions" div appears there is also a button "add new option" that when is clicked it should appear another input text so the user can insert a new option value. Each option should also have always a remove button associated that when is clicked the user can remove that input text, but it should be always a minimum of one input text.

Do you know how to do this properly? I have the working example below but it's working neither the append nor the remove.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/udx6pp8u/15/

**HTML:**

```
  <form id="" method="post" class="clearfix" action="">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputName">Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Type of Field</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="customQuestionType">
      <option>Text</option>
      <option>Long text</option>
      <option id="optionQuestion">Checkboxes</option>
      <option id="optionQuestion">Radiobuttons</option>
      <option id="optionQuestion">Select Menu </option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group" id="availableOptions">
    <label for="inputName">Available Options </label>
    <div class="option">
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
      <button id="removeOption">Remove Option</button>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
      <button id="removeOption">Remove Option</button>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary mt-3" id="addNewOption">Add new Option</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right mt-3" value="Store"/>

</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
#availableOptions{display:none;}
```

**jQuery:**

```
var selected_option = $('#customQuestionType option:selected').attr('id');

if (selected_option == "optionQuestion") {
    $('#availableOptions').show();
    if ($('#addNewOption').click(function() {
            $('#availableOptions')
                .append('<div class="option"><input type="text" class="form-control"><button id="removeOption">Remove Option</button></div>');
        }));
    if ($('#removeOption').click(function() {
            $('#availableOptions') // how to remove the clicked otpion?
        }));

}
```

Comment: Take a look at `element.appendChild()` and `element.removeChild()` at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Note: Don't use id. Use class instead. One document should only have one unique id. Using multiple id="removeOption" will coz your script to behave incorrectly and also choose the first found and ignore the rest having the same id

```
$('#customQuestionType').change(function(){
  var selected_option = $('option:selected', this).val();

  if (selected_option == "optionQuestion") {
    $('#availableOptions').show();
    $('#addNewOption').click(function() {
    $('#availableOptions').append('<div class="option"><input type="text" class="form-control"><button id="removeOption">Remove Option</button></div>');
    });
  }
});

$(document).on('click', '.removeOption', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('.option').remove();
})
```

DEMO:

https://jsfiddle.net/dL7opvak/21/

EDITED

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the available options div (#availableOptions) should only appear when is selected an option from the select menu that has a class of "optionQuestion", that is if the selected option is a checkbox, radio button or select menu. Also, the append is still not working.

Comment: I have edited the script to demonstrate the #customQuestionType part of the script. Again, avoid duplicating "unique" id

Comment: I have updated it again so your inputs dynamically added can also be removed

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to add the new input text when "Add new option" is clicked before the "Add new option" button instead of after the "add new option" button?

Comment: Simply move your div:
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary mt-3" id="addNewOption">Add new Option</button>
  </div>
Out of your id="customQuestionType"
https://jsfiddle.net/dL7opvak/27/